# Why does the figure vanish when controlled by a slider?

Tags: html, three.js

My idea, using three.js, is changing the speed of rotation of a cube by moving a slider control. Once I have defined the scene, the camera and the cube, the relevant code in the JavaScript part is like this:

```
var speed = 0.01;

function selectSpeed() {
    speed = document.getElementById("speedSelector").value;
}

function render() {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    cube.rotation.x += speed;
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

render();
```

Whereas the relevant code in the HTML part is this one:

```
<input id="speedSelector" type="range" min="0" max="0.1" step="0.005" value="0.01" onchange="selectSpeed()" />
```

When you open the webpage you can see the cube rotating fine and the slider control, but when you move the slider control to change the rotation speed, the cube disappears forever and you can't watch it anymore.

Anyone knows why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your speed variable is probably getting converted to string, try this:

```
speed = document.getElementById("speedSelector").value * 1.0;
```